# Does an approved glossary of translation industry terms exist?

Tags: terminology, translation

I'm kind of a beginner in the translation industry, and using different tools and talking to different people I find that they all use different terms to name the same things.

That is really confusing and I'm unsure which terms should I use regarding translation industry terms.

**For example:**

- exact match/ context match/ in-context match
- TB/Glossary/ Termbase/ Term Base
- fuzzy repetition/ internal match/ homogeneity /internal repetition/  internal fuzzy match

I've already seen several Glossaries prepared by the agencies, but still, those terms are specific for their companies, not all the industry uses the same terms.

**Here're some of the glossaries I've found:**

- [Logos](https://www.logos.net/translation-glossary/)
- [RixTrans](https://www.rixtrans.com/glossary-of-translation-industry-terms)
- [Word Awareness](https://www.wordawareness.com/terminology/)

**Is there one approved glossary of translation industry terms?**